# Find $S(\theta)$ (area of triangle)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: Find $S(\theta)$ ?

[image]

Comment: Hint: $OQ\cdot OP=OA^2$ since $OA$ is the tangent line of the circle

Comment: That's a nice picture.  How did you make it?

Comment: using smartdraw7

Comment: Young: Any reason why you did not accept the answer in your question here?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320068/how-to-find-int-01h-nxdx/320140#320140  In fact, out of 58 questions asked, you have accepted only 2.  High standards indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A(\Delta QPA) = A(\Delta OPF) - A(\Delta OQA) - A(\Delta APF)$, where $F$ is the foot of the perpendicular drawn from $P$ to the $X$ axis.

Note that

$$A(\Delta OPF) = \frac12 OP^2 \sin{\theta} \cos{\theta}$$
$$A(\Delta OQA) = \frac12 OQ \sin{\theta}$$
$$A(\Delta APF) = \frac12 OP \sin{\theta} (OP \cos{\theta}-1)$$

After a little algebra, I get that

$$A(\Delta QPA) = \frac12 (OP-OQ) \sin{\theta} $$

We find $P$ and $Q$ from the intersection of the circle $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=1$ and the line $y=\tan{\theta} x$.  After some algebra (which I will leave for the reader), I find that

$$OP = \cos{\theta} + \sin{\theta} + \sqrt{2 \sin{\theta} \cos{\theta}}$$
$$OQ = \cos{\theta} + \sin{\theta} - \sqrt{2 \sin{\theta} \cos{\theta}}$$

and therefore

$$A(\Delta QPA) = \sin{\theta} \sqrt{\sin{2 \theta}}$$

Note that $OP \cdot OQ = 1$ as Shuchang pointed out.